# List index out of range when trying to authenticate on onedrive SDK - python

Tags: python, ms-office, onedrive, index-error

I'm trying to use Onedrive SDK and at first I was able to authenticate fine with the code found here:
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python#authentication

I'm using onedrive for business.

However after some time of work it's no throwing this error

```
    service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Yet this is on line 33 (before i changed anything) making me very confused.

I've checked through these sites which seemed to have the same problem:
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/issues/60

Yet the solutions aren't working and I've (hopefully) set the right permissions as demonstrated here:
[App permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljo1s.png)

This is what I have currently (sensitive info censored):

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_id = 'xxxx'
client_secret = 'xxx'
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=discovery_uri)
service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)
```

(Which was exactly what they suggest to use on GitHub)

Any ideas as to what's going on?